# RouteConfig in ASP.NET MVC C# sent to error page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm setting up a new server with MVC **5.2.4.0** in ASP.NET. My problem is with the route configuration.

In the configuration file *App_Start/RouteConfig.cs* I have put the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultEvent",
    url: "{idseries}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { idseries= "startgate", idsequel = "SG1", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultEdition",
    url: "{idseries}/{idsequel}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { idseries= "stargate", idsequel = "SG1", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I want to use this urls which format are:

```
url:port
url:port/stargate
url:port/stargate/episode/actors
url:port/stargate/episode/actors/ONeill

url:port/stargate/SG1
url:port/stargate/SG1/episode/actors
url:port/stargate/SG1/episode/actors/ONeill
```

I had understood that ASP.NET tried to find the first **MapRoute** that does not fail, but it is not like that.

I have used Visual Studio Debugger but this only enters the file *RouteConfig.cs* at the first execution.

Also, I have created MapRoutes to cover all the combinations but it only enters the first entry. And if it does not enter it fails, showing the 404 error page.

Examples:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultEvent",
    url: "{idseries}/{controller}",
     defaults: new { idseries= "startgate", idsequel = "SG1", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultEdition",
    url: "{idseries}/{idsequel}",
    defaults: new { idseries= "stargate", idsequel = "SG1", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With this configuration it fails if I do not put a valid driver.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultEdition",
    url: "{idseries}/{idsequel}",
    defaults: new { idseries= "stargate", idsequel = "SG1", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultEvent",
    url: "{idseries}/{controller}",
     defaults: new { idseries= "startgate", idsequel = "SG1", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But if I put it upside down, it counts as the id of the sequel (which I see logic).

Comment: Are you using Attribute routing or Convention routing? Normally, unless you are using `Areas`, the `Controller` should go first in the routing.

Comment: Then, does ASP.NET only try the first option and the next ones ignore them?